# Page up / Page down PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class program(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_PageUp:
            print(1)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_PageUp:
            print(2)
```

Прочитал в документации, что должен работать следующий код, но у меня не работает (вывод чисел не происходит)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать второго родителя в класс `program`

Answer (score 2):

все работает

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Program(QMainWindow): #, Ui_MainWindow):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_PageUp:
            print('Key_PageUp')
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_PageDown:    # Key_PageUp:
            print('PageDown')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Program()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]